# jquery RateYo not working after render on Livewire

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-livewire

I'm using jQuery RateYo plugin for showing star ratings on my product card. First time when the page loads it work perfectly, But when I sort value by Livewire it will not showing star rating. In my livewire component render method I use this

```
  $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
```

And into my blade I try this

```
 window.addEventListener('contentChanged', (e) => {      
    for (let index = 1; index <= 5; index++) {
        $(".rating_" + index).rateYo({
            rating: index,
            normalFill: "#CCC",
            ratedFill: "#FFC700",
            spacing: "5px",
            fullStar: true,
            starWidth: "16px"
        });
    }
});
```

But it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to show rating properly after livewire component render?

I tried to dispaly card with rating without page load by Livewire. But it's not working. It only work when page is reload.